# try/catch throws error

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

With the help from good samaritans from stackoverflow, I have come till the following code to catch exceptions when the input from user is not an integer:

```
signed int num;

while(true)
{
    cin >> num;
    try{
       if(cin.fail()){
           throw "error";
       }
       if(num>0){
           cout<<"number greater than 0"<<endl;
       }
   }
   catch( char* error){
      cout<<error<<endl;
          break;
   }
}
```

Now assume the program is called: checkint. If I call the program by redirecting the input from a text file, say: input.txt, which has the following contents:
12 5 12 0 3 2 0

```
checkint <input.txt
```

Output:
I get the following output:

```
number greater than 0
number greater than 0
number greater than 0
number greater than 0
number greater than 0
error
```

Why is it throwing the error in the end, when all the input in the file are integers?
Thanks

Comment: Note that `"error"` is an rvalue of `char[6]`, which will bind to to `const char[6]`, and `const char*`, but IMO should not to bind to `char*`. (IOW, your exception would not be caught.)

Comment: Using exceptions to handle malformed user input sounds like abuse to me; I suggest to rather read in a `std::string` and then use a function like `bool isInteger( const std::string &s )` to verify that the given input is indeed an integer according to your formatting requirements.

Comment: It's also poor form to throw things that aren't derived from `std::exception`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are detecting eof too. Read up on `.good()`, `.bad()`, `.eof()` and `.fail()`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/iostate/

```
flag value  indicates
eofbit  End-Of-File reached while performing an extracting operation on an input stream.
failbit The last input operation failed because of an error related to the internal logic of the operation itself.
badbit  Error due to the failure of an input/output operation on the stream buffer.
goodbit No error. Represents the absence of all the above (the value zero).
```

Try this:

```
while(cin >> num)
{
    if(num>0){
        cout<<"number greater than 0"<<endl;
    }
}

// to reset the stream state on parse errors:
if (!cin.bad()) 
   cin.clear(); // if we stopped due to parsing errors, not bad stream state
```

If you prefer getting the exception, try

```
cin.exceptions(istream::failbit | istream::badbit);
```

Loose notes:

- using streams in exception mode is not common practice
- throwing primitive types is not common practice. Consider writing

.

```
 #include <stdexcept>

 struct InputException : virtual std::exception 
 {  
     protected: InputException() {}
 };

 struct IntegerInputException : InputException 
 {
     char const* what() const throw() { return "IntegerInputException"; }
 };

 // ... 
 throw IntegerInputException();

 //
 try
 {
 } catch(const InputException& e)
 {
      std::cerr << "Input error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: added 'good practice' exception handling sample, see also http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html

Comment: @user1035927: you don't, you set the exception mask _before_ entering the loop. And you may want to call `.clear()` after handling the error(s)

Comment: sehe, thanks a lot for all your help. I seem to get it working by placing the condition: if(cin.eof()) break;                             Is it wise to do this?

Comment: @user1035927: I'd say, no. Rationale: you are further complicating control flow in a loop that was already roughly 3x longer than necessary. Of course, it does do what you intend, and your coding style is up to you. Just remember what the good samaritans say :)

Comment: "error" isn't an integral type. Maybe you meant "primitive" type? But that isn't really accurate, either. You want your exceptions to be derived specifically from `std::exception`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I think I showed quite comprehensive example of how to derive from std::exception. Fixing wording on integral type :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's because you always return to the `cin >> num` statement *even after you have read the final integer.*

If you change:

```
if (num > 0) {
    cout << "number greater than 0" << endl;
}
```

into:

```
if (num > 0) {
    cout << "number greater than 0\n";
} else {
    cout << "number less than or equal to 0\n";
}
```

you will no doubt see seven lines of output then the thrown error.

Answer (score 0):

because it reached EOF? You have 5 positive integers in your input, two times 0 (no output), and then EOF is reached.