# ambigious overload for operator>>’ in ‘getfile >> point’

Tags: c++

I keep getting the following error when I run this. Any help?

```
ambigious overload for ‘operator >> ’ in ‘getfile  >>  point’
```

this is my code in pp object

```
istream& pp::operator >> (istream& in)
{
    //error msg
    string msg = "Error. Output from file, String is found instead of integer. Please check file for errors\n";

    //ignore everything till next record
    in.ignore(256, '[');

    //store x cordinate
    in >> x;
    if(in.fail()){throw msg;}

    //ignore everything till next record
    in.ignore(256, ',');

    //store y cordinate
    in >> y;
    if(in.fail()){throw msg;}

    //ignore the rest of the records till next line
    in.ignore(256, '\n');

    return in;

}//end of operator >>  method
```

this is in my main

```
{   
     ifstream getfile;  
     //get filename to input data into system
     cout << "\nPlease enter filename : ";
     cin >> file;
     getfile.open(file, ios::in);

     pp pointObject();
     getfile >> point;
}
```

this is my pp.h structure where you guys want to see.

```
    class pp
    {
    public:
    //constructor
    pp();
    pp(int, int);
    pp(const Point2D &pd);

    //operator overloaded methods
    virtual pp operator-(pp pd);
    virtual bool operator<(pp pd) const;
    virtual bool operator>(pp pd) const;
    virtual bool operator==(pp pd);
    virtual ostream& operator<<(ostream& o) const;
    virtual istream& operator>>(istream& in;    

    //accessor,mutator methods
    int getX() const;
    int getY() const;

    void setX(int);
    void setY(int);

    protected:
    int x;
    int y;
    };
    #endif
```

Comment: Show the definition of `point`.

Comment: While nothing to do with your problem, you really shouldn't `throw` strings. Use one of the standard exceptions, like `runtime_error` instead, the constructor takes a string as parameter, which will be returned by the `exception::what` function.

Comment: The definition of `istream& pp::operator>>(istream&)` is not important. The declaration of `pp` would help much more, and also without the type of `getfile` and `point` (did you mean `pointObject`?) there is not much we can say.

Comment: hi guys i rectified the post as how you requested. hi Pileborg! could you enlighten me on the exception::what function? i am new to this. thanks! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operator>>` cannot be a member of the class, because that gives it the wrong order for the parameters. You have to consider the implicit `this` parameter for all member functions (and operators).

The signature should be `istream& operator>>(istream& in, pp& point)` to enable its use in `getfile >> point;`.

Comment: wierd thing, when i did the following above, i keep getting the following error in the header file. error: ‘std::istream& pp::operator>>(std::istream&, pp&)’ must take exactly one argument

Comment: If it is a member, there is the `this` parameter and the `istream`. That makes it two parameters, which is what the operator uses (and the compiler knows that). You can make it a friend of the class if you want or need to declare it inside the class. `friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, pp& point)` would be ok.

Comment: hi there, how do you declare the operator>> for a inherited class. i seem to be getting errors for my inherited classes.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of your `operator >>` should be:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, pp &p)
```

Then, in the body of the function, you should assign the `x` and `y` values read to `p.x` and `p.y`.

Comment: wierd thing, when i did the following above, i keep getting the following error in the header file.
error: ‘std::istream& pp::operator>>(std::istream&, pp&)’ must take exactly one argument

Comment: It has to be a free function, not a `pp` member function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a freestanding operator overload

**Note** also, Re: handling stream errors and using exceptions, see [try/catch throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209558/try-catch-throws-error/8209597#8209597)

```
friend istream& pp::operator>> (istream& in, pp& pointObject)
{
    //error msg
    const string msg = "ErPoint2Dror. Output from file, String is found instead of integer. Please check file for errors\n";

    //ignore everything till next record
    in.ignore(256, '[');

    int x,y;

    //store x cordinate
    in >> x;
    if(in.fail())
    {
        throw msg;
    }

    //ignore everything till next record
    in.ignore(256, ',');

    //store y cordinate
    in >> y;
    if(in.fail())
    {
        throw msg;
    }

    //ignore the rest of the records till next line
    in.ignore(256, '\n');

    pointObject.x = x;
    pointObject.y = y;

    return in;
}//end of operator >>  method
```

Comment: hi there i cant use friend as i have 4 other classes where i have to overload the same operator with diffrent functions! :D

Answer (score 0):

Best way to overload stream operators is to keep them as friends.

In your pp class declaration:

```
friend istream& operator >>(istream& in, pp& obj);
```

In your cpp file:

```
istream& operator>>(istream &in, pp& obj)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: If you don't need them to access private fields there's no need to make them `friend`s.

Comment: hi there i cant use friend as i have 4 other classes where i have to overload the same operator with diffrent functions! :D

Comment: You can overload the global operator>> multiple times with different objects: istream& operator >>(istream& in, pp1& obj); istream& operator >>(istream& in, pp2& obj);
so that shouldn't be an issue